# SP2010 Javascript Object Model: programmactially add calculated column to list

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, client-object-model, calculated-column

I am building lists and adding fields via the following. I am wondering if I can add a calculated field and how you set the formula in this (or another method):

```
function onCreateRootCause() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();   
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title('LedgerLikeList');
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(100);
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCreatedExampleList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}


function onCreatedExampleList() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Description');
    this.fieldValue = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\TransDescription\' Type=\Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
    var fieldVal= clientContext.castTo(fieldValue,SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldVal.set_defaultValue('[Example Ledger Transaction Description]');
    fieldVal.update();
    clientContext.load(fieldValue);

    this.fieldValue = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Income\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);  
    var fieldVal = clientContext.castTo(fieldValue,SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldVal.set_defaultValue(0.0);
    fieldVal.update();
    clientContext.load(fieldValue);

    this.fieldValue= oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Expenditures\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);   
    var fieldVal = clientContext.castTo(fieldValue,SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldVal.set_defaultValue(0.0);
    fieldVal.update();
    clientContext.load(fieldValue);

    // is there a way I can via this method, or another add a balance column that calculates as simple as Income - Expenditure = Balance (I know this is not complete, this list is just for example).


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCreatedFieldsCallback), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an example of Calculated field schema:

```
"<Field Type=\"Calculated\" " +
"DisplayName=\"New_Field_Display_Name\" ResultType=\"Currency\" " +
"ReadOnly=\"TRUE\" Name=\"New_Field_Internal_Name\">" +
"<Formula>=Currency_Field_Name*100</Formula>" +
"<FieldRefs><FieldRef Name=\"Currency_Field_Name\" />" + 
"</FieldRefs></Field>";
```

Code taken from below msdn link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457586.aspx

Even though the example there is for server object model, the code should work in client object model as well.